# Wrong print in PHPexcel large data from oci_fetch_array

Tags: php, excel, oracle, phpexcel, oracle-call-interface

Good afternoon!

Please, I need help with my code. I have a query that reads a large amount of data and prints it with oci_fetch_array but I need to export it in an Excel spreadsheet.

I use the code for PHPexcel 01simple-download-xls and fill the data:

```
$result = oci_parse($connect, $query);

oci_execute($result);

while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
$columna = 0;


        foreach ($row as $key => $valor) {

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A' . $columna,  $valor);


           $columna++; 

        }


}

oci_free_statement($result);
oci_close($connect);
```

But the spreadsheet only shows the first data of my bd, and I need all of it.

[image]

And the data is like this:
[image]

How can I print the data row in the columns?

Thanks!

Comment: It's okay. I'll just proofread it. Community edits are a thing here. Do you mind if I remove the bit at the end about your English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An MS Excel cell address comprises a column ID and a Row ID. Column IDs are letters (`A`, `B`, `C`, etc); Row IDs are numbers (`1`, `2`, `3`, etc): so a cell address like `B3` is column `B` and row `3`. (As you can see in your picture)

You're using a variable `$columna`, concatenating it with `A` to define a cell address like `A1` and incrementing it for each element, so your cell addresses are `A1,`A2`, A3`, etc.... always column `A`. So all your data will be in that first column. (You're also starting with row `0`, which doesn't exist.

Modify your code, to work with both row and column, giving yourself a cell address:

```
$rowNumber = 1;
while (($row = oci_fetch_array($result, OCI_BOTH)) != false){
    $columna = 'A';
    foreach ($row as $key => $valor) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columna . $rowNumber,  $valor);
        $columna++; 
    }
    $rowNumber++;
}
```

Start with row 1, not row 0.
Reset column after each $row

There are easier ways to do this, but unless you can grasp the concept of cell addresses, you'll have difficulty working with Excel files

Comment: is no work show me error  
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/consultaprocesado/PHPExcel_1.8.0_doc/Examples/01simple-download-xls.php on line 148 Fatal error:...

Comment: Let me guess which is line 148..... no, I can't guess, I can't see your code, I haven't a clue what line 148 is..... if you want help, you have to give us the occasional clue rather than simply say it doesn't work

Comment: Sorry for that i try to put the whole code but in can't tnks for the help

Comment: OK, my bad.... I used the same variable `$row` for the Excel row number as you use for the database row.... I've modified my code in the answer to use a different variable name

Comment: You might also want to change `OCI_BOTH` to either `OCI_ASSOC` or `OCI_NUM` in your fetch_array() statement to avoid duplicating the data

Comment: tnks for the help @mark-baker , and god day but i stiil showing an error 
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in CacheBase.php** on line 173, and this is the line 173
"public function getCellList() {
  return array_keys($this->_cellCache);
 } // function getCellList()"

Comment: I can't increase the amount of memory your PHP allows you to use, only you can do that; or alternatively, look at some of the caching methods that PHPExcel provides to reduce memory usage